# Selecting specific areas in a pointcloud

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud of this object

[image: Full point cloud]

And I want to measure the distance between the plane where the piece is sitting on and the points marked as red, and as blue. I already have the plane equation, allowing me to remove the points corresponding to the plane and to calculate the distance between it and the points. But I can't figure out how to select the red and blue points, any methods that could help solve this problem?

[image: Point Cloud without the plane]

Comment: Plz correct my understanding. You are trying to find the distance between a plane for which you know the equation, and a known point. `float distance = dotProduct(planeNormal, pointInPlane - point));`

Comment: The problem is in selecting those specific points and not in the distance calculation itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your cloud has **high quality normals**, you can try to leverage the discontinuities between the sub-parts using
   [pcl::RegionGrowing](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/region_growing_segmentation.html#region-growing-segmentation) with a strict smoothness criteria (If the deviation between points normals is less than the smoothness threshold then they are suggested to be in the same cluster).
2. If you **know the size** of all sub-parts, you can calculate an oriented bounding-box, and then (roughly) cut-out the two round parts.
3. If you don't know the size, then after you calculate an oriented bounding-box (and rotate so that x is the long axis - for example), you bin the x values, and calculate for each x, the min/max y values. This should give you a sense of it's shape.

Either way, once you have a sub-part, you can calculate it's center of mass, and then calculate for each point, the distance to the center. This will give you a distribution of radius.

1. If you have finer sub-parts (from method #1 above), you can determine which is what by considering the mean and min radius.
2. If you have a rough sub-part (from method #2/#3 above), you should segment points as "red"/"blue" based on the radius. You might have to do this iteratively (refining the center of mass each time).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I want to automate this procedure, so there is any way to always select the same region when using the region-growing? Or is it better to use the bounding-box method?

Comment: Region Growing uses the point with lowest curvature to determine next seed point, so the sub-regions should be consistent. You shouldn't count on their order (they are sorted by size). You need to go over all sub-regions and analyze them (as in #1 in the last part of the answer). Assuming the normals discontinuities are indeed good enough in your case, I think it's a better direction to follow. Same concept can be extended by introducing different validation / criteria to test the sub-regions, such as classification of the subparts.